# Do I need UIRequiresPersistentWiFi for this type of app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm creating RSS reader application, and just wanted to know do I really need to include UIRequiresPersistentWiFi in my Info.plist file?

The only case I would find is the user read really long (loaded) article (or he read slowly) for more than 30 minutes, and boom the wi-fi get off, and he need to turn it back on.

This is super rare I know but I'm just concerned...

Thank you!

Comment: is 3g/cellular line fast enough to load your (small) RSS data? could your app work well on cellular lines?

Comment: It's not small, and Wi-Fi is recommended.

Comment: then, you are the only one who can answer... recommended is not "a must"... but you are the only one who can judge if 3g velocity is acceptable

Answer (score 0):

While it wouldn't be required for this type of app, for the user experience sake, I would present a dialog to the user upon the application first running to let them know that WiFi is not required, but is highly recommended. Maybe include a setting, letting the user choose if they want to put the app in "WiFi-only mode." This can be especially helpful as more and more carriers are switching to limited iPhone data plan models.